# Issue addin sharepoint list item with mutli people field with rest

Tags: reactjs, rest, sharepoint, spfx

I'm trying to add a list item with rest api in sharepoint online.

I tried few format, I don't have issue, the item is added, but the multi people field stay empty.

in my json file the field is formatted like this :

```
{...
   '__metadata' : { 'type': 'Collection(Edm.Int32)' }, // with and without this line
   AssignedToId : { "results" : [0]}
}
```

or

```
{...
   AssignedToStringId : { "results" : ["0"] }
}
```

or

```
{...
   AssignedToId : { "results" : ["0"] }
}
```

The item is saved, other fields are ok, but the people one is still empty.

do you know where should be the problem ?

EDIT : I used Results and not the array directly. sending array directly cause an error. here I don't have any error, just the field empty.

Answer (score 0):

Some ways require you to encapsulate array values in `{ results: [your array] }`, you may try

```js
{
  AssignedToId: [13, 17, 21]
}
```

or

```js
{
  AssignedToId: { results: [13, 17, 21] }
}
```

From what I've used, __metadata is never mandatory, and the name of the field should always be `[Field Internal Name]Id` when assigning through ID. Also, IDs are numbers, not strings

Comment: dam, I recopied with error, I tested with results to :
"{\"__metadata\":{\"type\":\"SP.Data.TasksListItem\"},\"Title\":\"trgrdfgfdgfgdgfdgdg\",\"Date\":\"2023-03-17T04:00:00.000Z\",\"Description\":\"gdgfgd\",\"AssignedToId\":{\"results\":[\"0\"]}}"

Comment: Which is an error since ids are numbers and you just pasted `:{\"results\":[\"0\"]}`